# Can Active Pivot dimension/measure field names or aliases contain spaces?

Tags: activepivot

A search of the QuartetFS Confluence for 'field name spaces' gives little other than a snippet of a document saying:

```
The names are shown here with spaces, for clarity; in ActivePivot, the names do not have spaces
```

"Do not have spaces" doesn't mean "can not have spaces" so I am curious if we can safely use spaces in the field names or create a alias with spaces that points to a field name without spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the following item can contain spaces:

- Schema field name
- Cube level name / property
- Cube dimension name
- Cube measure name / property

Could you give the URL of the documentation page you quoted? This should be fixed.

Comment: This is the search page: http://support.quartetfs.com/confluence/dosearchsite.action?queryString=field+name+spaces.  I was quoting from the "Active Pivot Guide".